# How to write json in specific format in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to display JSON in specific format and data will be from database.So how to form in specific format in python.Format of JSON is

```
 {
       "data":{"Device Id" : value from db,"Date":Current Time},
       "Data":
       {
          "Temperature":
              {
                value from db
              },
         "Consumptions":
            {
                value from db
            },
         "Error":
           [
              {
                 value from db
              }
           ]
       }
    }
```

I have tried this:

```
dict((query.description[i][0], value) for i, value in enumerate(row)) for row in query.fetchall()
```

But I'm not getting desired output and i'm unable to pass data to json. So how to pass data to json.

**Error Im getting is Dictionay update sequence element 0# has length 1; 2 is required**

Answer (score 0):

Did you use `json` module?

```
import json

print json.dumps(yourStructure, indent=6)
```

Comment: I did that bt Its giving error when passing db value to json

Comment: This should mean your JSON is not valid

Comment: Have checked on json validator its not giving error

Comment: @AnkitaAgharkar Edit your question to include the error you're getting